# Rooting and run adbd service automatically

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, rooting, adb, root-access, odin

I try to use create root package that run adbd service automatically,so:

1. I download root package for gti9300 from autoroot.chainfire.eu
2. I extract package multiple times to get recovery.img and cache.img
3. [Unpack it](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=HOWTO%3a_Unpack,_Edit,_and_Re-Pack_Boot_Images)
4. So I opened and edited default.prop like this:

   > ro.secure=0
   >
   > ro.debuggable=1
   >
   > persist.sys.usb.config=mtp,adb
5. Pack recovery ...
6. Going mobile to download mode
7. Upload it with odin

It roots completely OK but it's not running adb service.

How can I root and run adb server at the same time? (I want avoid going to download mode one time)

Answer (score -1):

use adbd insecure app then enable it (also at boot). give it root permissions using superuser pro v1.0  and reboot your phone. I did it to gain default shell as root on my phone samsung galaxy star duos.

Comment: tanx for try to help me but i know about apps like insecure adbd or i can run adbd insecure using shell or ... i just want create a root pack (recovery.img) for rooting and running adbd service ;) and i want to create something like root packs in autoroot.chainfire.eu with only some changes like running adbd..